# Find centroid of polygon area

Tags: c#, geometry

I have these sets of points:

```
{X = 3.142888 Y = 101.633827}
{X = 3.142325 Y = 101.633827}
{X = 3.142023 Y = 101.633759}
{X = 3.141899 Y = 101.633652}
{X = 3.141045 Y = 101.633659}
{X = 3.141433 Y = 101.634193}
{X = 3.141291 Y = 101.6343}
{X = 3.141381 Y = 101.634415}
{X = 3.141194 Y = 101.634895}
{X = 3.141618 Y = 101.6349}
{X = 3.142697 Y = 101.634239}
```

I tried using the method by http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/07/find-the-centroid-of-a-polygon-in-c/

```
public PointF FindCentroid()
{
    // Add the first point at the end of the array.
    int num_points = Points.Length;
    PointF[] pts = new PointF[num_points + 1];
    Points.CopyTo(pts, 0);
    pts[num_points] = Points[0];

    // Find the centroid.
    float X = 0;
    float Y = 0;
    float second_factor;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
    {
        second_factor =
            pts[i].X * pts[i + 1].Y -
            pts[i + 1].X * pts[i].Y;
        X += (pts[i].X + pts[i + 1].X) * second_factor;
        Y += (pts[i].Y + pts[i + 1].Y) * second_factor;
    }

    // Divide by 6 times the polygon's area.
    float polygon_area = PolygonArea();
    X /= (6 * polygon_area);
    Y /= (6 * polygon_area);

    // If the values are negative, the polygon is
    // oriented counterclockwise so reverse the signs.
    if (X < 0)
    {
        X = -X;
        Y = -Y;
    }

    return new PointF(X, Y);
}
```

But the result is way off :

```
{X = 3.11197066 Y = 100.614342}
```

Is there anything I missed here?

Thank you

Comment: is it ? x=3.142,y=101.634 https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Uha.png

Comment: Could you double check if your polygon is not self-intersecting? According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon this is a requirement to this formula.

Comment: The problem might be that C# `float` doesn't have very high precision. Your X coordinated vary only from the fourth digit, and the Y coordinates only from the sixth digit. The precision of `float` is only ~6-9 digits.

Comment: It's like you're looking at the problem from very far away, your points are somewhere near (3.14, 101.63), but the difference between them is so small compared to their distance from (0, 0). What happens if you try to "zoom" in on the problem by only keeping the interesting decimal positions in the coordinates, i.e. by subtracting 3.14 from every X-coordinate and 101.63 from each Y-coordinate before calling the function?